Is it possible to add a certificate in the istio-proxy container?
I have a microservice inside a pod that calls a api management.
The management api has custom domains with self-signed certificates and currently the microservice calls the management api over http.
What I need is to start calling the api management via https, so an alternative would be to install the root certificate in the pod, but I wanted to know if that certificate can be installed in the istio?
When we use istio, I see that in all the pods, we have a container named istio-proxy.
I want to know if is it possible to install a certificate in thtat container?
And if possible, how to ensure that all pods have that certificate installed when they are created?
